# Facebook Graph API OAuthException Code: 9 Access denied. Why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, exception, oauth

I am using facebook Graph API to get user data with the below query

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=xxx yyy zzzz&type=user&access_token=myTokenHere
```

And the reply is;

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#9) Access denied",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 9
   }
}
```

And also it makes my account to logoff from developer.facebook.com. When I try refreshing that web site it says I am logged out.

I am used to use this account for making this search, this happened suddenly. I made maybe a thousand successful search with this link, with this user with this query.

It doesn't says I am limited or something.

I googled it a lot and made a lot of research but couldn't find any solution to it.

Comment: " I made maybe a thousand successful search with this link,"
What did it say when you were logged out? It sounds like your account is detected as being compromised because of really bizarre search activity

Comment: Well I got another account detected as "suspicious activity and locked for 24 hours" but this one didn't said anything like that.

At the end, after a while (maybe after couple of hours) I am able to make search with this account. I think it's kind of obstructed but didn't gave an error like "you are rate limited, please calm down and wait" and gave this weird error.

Comment: Any clues about the code 9?